# Does the ArcGIS Flex API simplify polygons by default?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, feature-layer, map-service

I have a feature access map service that I use on an ArcGIS Flex web application.
Some polygons published by the feature service, seem to be "simplified" by the Flex API before they are drawn on the map.
The original shape of the polygons is ellipsoidal, like potatoes. But they are drawn like hexagons or octagons with summits and sharp angles.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Have you confirmed that coordinates are being returned from the feature service but are not being included in the flex polygon?  On the server does the original feature contain [elliptic arcs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000011t000000)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall "Have you confirmed that coordinates are being returned from the feature service but are not being included in the flex polygon?"
I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall "On the server does the original feature contain elliptic arcs?"
The feature class was created by ArcCatalog and I didn't see any option about elliptic arcs when I was creating the class.